# virtualenvwrapper install failure - "what would cause ImportError: No module named core" etc?

Tags: python

I'm on osx 10.6.8, and trying to use bash to install virtualenvwrapper, and am getting back cryptic feedback (at least for me).
I was able to install virtualenv.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction...

the output from the failed install:

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenvwrapper
```

Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenvwrapper

```
Installed /private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper/pbr-0.5.23-py2.6.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py:245: UserWarning: Module pbr was already imported from /tmp/easy_install-xuBV6G/pbr-0.5.23/pbr/__init__.py, but /private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper/pbr-0.5.23-py2.6.egg is being added to sys.path
  working_set.add(dist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    pbr=True,
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py", line 223, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py", line 256, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1907, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named core
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
```

Installed /private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper/pbr-0.5.23-py2.6.egg

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py:245: UserWarning: Module pbr was already imported from /tmp/easy_install-xuBV6G/pbr-0.5.23/pbr/**init**.py, but /private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper/pbr-0.5.23-py2.6.egg is being added to sys.path

working_set.add(dist)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 16, in

File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py", line 7, in

```
pbr=True,
```

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup

```
_setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
```

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py", line 223, in **init**

```
_Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
```

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 270, in **init**

```
self.finalize_options()
```

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/dist.py", line 256, in finalize_options

```
ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
```

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1907, in load

```
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
```

ImportError: No module named core

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/virtualenvwrapper
Storing complete log in /Users/admin/Library/Logs/pip.log

Comment: I suspect there is a versioning issue here - but no attempted updates/installs have fixed it as of yet
python --version returns Python 2.7.4 -- perhaps there is a configuration issue I need to address?

Comment: Thinking I'll check into my Mac environment setup and make sure everything uses Python 2.7 - the last lines seem to be calling 2.6 for some reason; I did pip install that got pip2 into the 2.7 framework

Comment: Running sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper results in Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.2.tar.gz

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Updating `pbr` package using `pip install -U pbr` globally solved the import issue.